# ifstream getline of string into Array?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, getline

I'm trying to use this function

```
int input(int marks[classMax][3], string names[classMax], float& avg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            fin >> marks[i][j];
        }
        fin >> names[i];
    }
}
```

to get a list of marks with student names into two arrays. The list is as follows:
`M1 M2 M3 FirstName LastName`, where M means Mark.
the loop is working fine but when it reaches the space between First and Last Name the program seems to write only the FirstName into the array. I tried using `fin.get` and `fin.getline()` but I'm getting this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::get(std::strings&, int)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
int input(int marks[classMax][3], string names[classMax], float& avg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<students; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            fin >> marks[i][j];
        }
        std::getline(fin, names[i]);
    }
}
```

For more information check out [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 1):

[`std::basic_istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) does not take `std::string`.

[`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is what you want to use with `std::string`. Since it's a non-member function template, call it with an input stream as a first parameter and the output string as a second:

```
std::getline(fin, names[i]);
```